# PHP pages stopped working on Nginx with reverse proxy for Apache

Tags: ubuntu, apache-http-server, proxy, php, nginx

I set up a Nginx server with reverse proxy for Apache (following this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-nginx-as-a-web-server-and-reverse-proxy-for-apache-on-one-ubuntu-20-04-server)) some months ago. Everything work great, the nginx part as well as the php pages on Apache.

But I needed to use curl for php and therefore I installed the php-curl package with

```shell
sudo apt install php-curl
```

Ever since I only get "500 Internal Server Error" for all the php pages. The nginx pages and html pages still work fine.

I'm not sure how to find the culprit for this. I tried uninstalling the package again and restarted the service `sudo systemctl reload apache2` (with is active and `sudo systemctl status apache2` shows no error)

This is in the error logs (`/var/log/apache2/error.log`) though:

```
[fastcgi:error] [pid 9587:tid 140151397275200] (2)No such file or directory: [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:49342] FastCGI: failed to connect to server "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/php-fcgi": connect() failed
[fastcgi:error] [pid 9587:tid 140151397275200] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:49342] FastCGI: incomplete headers (0 bytes) received from server "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/php-fcgi"
```

PS: I'm not sure if this is relevant, but I set up the server on ubuntu 21.10 and updated to 22.10 shortly before it stopped working. It definitely still worked after the update, but maybe the services were not restarted during the update and installing php-curl triggered a restart?

Comment: Do you mean it still DIDN'T work after that?

Comment: My apologies, that was poorly written, I tried to clarify

Answer (score 1):

The issue was in the file `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/fastcgi.conf`, which looked like this for me:

```
<IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
  AddHandler fastcgi-script .fcgi
  FastCgiIpcDir /var/lib/apache2/fastcgi
  AddType application/x-httpd-fastphp .php
  Action application/x-httpd-fastphp /php-fcgi
  Alias /php-fcgi /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php-fcgi
  FastCgiExternalServer /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php-fcgi -socket /run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock -pass-header Authorization
  <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</IfModule>
```

I suspected that the `php7.4` might cause problems since I run php8. I double-checked php version on the server (with `php --version`) and changed the respective line accordingly:

```
FastCgiExternalServer /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php-fcgi -socket /run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock -pass-header Authorization
```

I then restarted apache (`sudo systemctl status apache2.service`) and it now seems to work again.

---

It is still irritating to me that the `Alias` folder `/usr/lib/cgi-bin/php-fcgi` doesn't exist (`/usr/lib/cgi-bin` is in fact empty). I suspected that might was my problem (see [Unable to install PHP-FPM on Apache (Failed to connect to FastCGI server)](https://serverfault.com/questions/437514/unable-to-install-php-fpm-on-apache-failed-to-connect-to-fastcgi-server)), which made check `fastcgi.conf` in the first place. But since everything seems to work, I will just go with it for now.